# GLSL can still see triangles after normal mapping

Tags: c++, opengl, mapping, glsl

I was under the assumption that normal mapping should eliminate the visibility of triangles on a mesh, as lighting will be calculated based on unique normals per fragment instead of per vertex. As you can see in the image below, the normal map is definitely working but triangles are still visible. Is this an error?

[image]

I compute tangents as follows :

```
vec3 vert1( vertices[a+1] - vertices[a] );
vec3 vert2( vertices[a+2] - vertices[a] );
vec2 uv1( uvs[a+1] - uvs[a] );
vec2 uv2( uvs[a+2] - uvs[a] );

float r = (uv1.x * uv2.y) - (uv1.y * uv2.x);
vec3 tangent(vert1 * uv2.y - vert2 * uv1.y)*r;
```

Vertex Shader :

```
mat3 TBN_MATRIX;
TBN_MATRIX[0]   = (MODEL_MATRIX * vec4( tangent,0 )).xyz;
TBN_MATRIX[2]   = (MODEL_MATRIX * vec4( normal,0 )).xyz;
TBN_MATRIX[1]   = cross( TBN_MATRIX[2], TBN_MATRIX[0] );
```

Fragment Shader :

```
fragment_normal = normalize( TBN_MATRIX * vec3(( 2 * texture( normal_map, uv_coordinates ).rgb ) - 1.0 ) );
```

My first thought is that a cross product is somehow not enough for the bitangent?

Comment: You have solid normals, that means that each triangle has it's own normal. You should assign normals per vertex by interpolating between the normal of each triangle adjacent to the vertex. *This* is what "hides" the triangles. Normal mapping is more often used to obtain additional detail with the same number of triangles.

Comment: No, normal mapping will not hide triangles. For that, you need some form of culling. Usually it is done by the winding direction of the triangle in screen-space.

Comment: problem solved. When I was indexing verts the algorithm wasnt merging verts at the same position, because it was also testing to see if the normals were identical.. and for some reason blender was exporting identical verts with differing normals. thanks.

Comment: If you set "Shading" to "Smooth" for the object (under "Object Tools") Blender should export the mesh with shared vertices.